# How to match `?session` in android pathPattern

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to use android deeplink for urls that include `?session`

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```xml
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*?session.*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that is not possible. You cannot match on query parameters (i.e., `?` and anything after that).